# Android on menu item click change visibility of check box

Tags: android, menuitem

I need to change checkbox visibility depending on menu item click. I have done this and I'm getting Null pointer exeptions.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menu_edit_trips +1) {
        mEditCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mEditCheckBox = (CheckBox) mFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.editTripCheckBox);

}
```

Can anyone know how can I do this correctly?

Comment: what is `mFragmentView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct way is to `findViewById` inside the `onCreateView` :

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child, container, false);
mEditCheckBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.editTripCheckBox);
```

Where `inflater` is the 1st parameter of the `onCreateView`

Answer (score 0):

create a handler and update your view from there. call handler when menu item is clicked.